# How to recess baseboards in remodel

Tags: drywall, framing, carpentry

I am replacing my floors and it’s turned into a full remodel, with lots of skim coating my wall/ceilings).
I want recessed baseboards.  Not very common but a look I really like.  All the construction details I see are from new construction with blocking between the studs to provide flush/level support for the baseboards to be even with the drywall.

My plan is to

1. Remove existing flooring, level underlayment, lay the new flooring next to drywall and mark top of new baseboards+ 3/4” reveal
2. Cut drywall at mark along wall and attach a tape on L or Z drywall bead.
3. Skim coat wall
4. Install flooring
5. Install baseboards.  Scribe / plane baseboards as needed for flush fit.

Questions:

- Would shimming behind studs provide a flush surface with drywall?
- Any clever ideas to help me achieve the look I am going for?

Comment: Do you have an example picture of the "look you are going for?"

Answer (score 4):

Consider "reglet" to cap over the drywall with the one leg against the stud so the base can cover it, to create a gap to the base. It is available in various depths to work with different thicknesses of wall and base material.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Including an actual picture of the items in question would be helpful in the future when (not if) that link dies.

Comment: I was going to bed soon, didn't take the time to do so, will edit to include when I get back from work.